# How to load jQuery from the iframe to its parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, bigcommerce

I have a below code in my iframe and it contain some jQuery and I want to call it from the iframe to parent page but it not working and path of the iframe is the `content/test/doubleimg.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com/content/test/base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com/content/test/doubleimg.js"></script>
```

And double img contain some jQuery function which is execute onload of the page and it work fine but if i put it in iframe its not working.

And my html markup like and path of the parent file is `template/category.html`

```
<div id="Container">
-----------
-----------
      <div class="Content" id="LayoutColumn2">
               <iframe id="theiframe" allowtransparency="true" target="_top" src="/content/test/doubleimg.html" frameborder="0" height="0" width="0"></iframe>
      </div>
</div>
```

So please suggest me the idea how can I use jQuery from the iframe and my jQuery is execute on the page load.

Actually I am trying to call api of the Bigcommerce but for that I need to set https and I can't set it because it not allowed in the Bigcommerce to set https in category page url

And if I am not set https then the API returns a `401 authentication error`

So please help me out from this.

Comment: Assuming same origin, [`window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.parent) will access the _Window_ object of the parent frame, if any. If no parent, it will give the same as `window`

Comment: And why would you put it in an iFrame ?

Comment: @adeneo please check my edited question why i am put it in iframe

Comment: @adeneo i am trying to access the Bigcommerce api but it not work if i have http in the url if i set https in the url it work fine so finaly i am try to acess it via iframe

Answer (score 2):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/kZF3n/), if documents are in the same domain:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var jQuery = iframe.contentWindow.jQuery;
alert(jQuery);
```

See my [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/kZF3n/) for more information. It include other jsfiddle in iframe there I inited jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
window.parent.document.wirte('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>');
```

Comment: Are you sure it would be wise to use `document.write()` in a document, which has been parsed already. Also writing a script with another script will fail with your code.